# How to convert array values to string format

Tags: php

I have the input array in following format:

> "123,46,78,000";

But I need it in this format:

> '123','46','78','000';

can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's devide this string into the array.

```
$var =  "123,46,78,000";
$array = explode(',',$var);
```

after that we can merge all array into string using implode function.

```
$finaloutput = "'" . implode ( "', '", $array ) . "'";
echo $finaloutput;
```

now, you will get the exact output which you need.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Its solve my issue ,I got a output as expected,Thank you so much .

Comment: Welcome @kanidhaya